# Always call superclass virtual function when child override is called

Tags: c++

I have this structure:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void func(int a)
    {
        cout << "System is initiated correctly." << a;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void func(int a) override
    {
        A::func(a);
        cout << "This particular system is initiated correctly too" << a;
    }
};
```

Now in 95% cases when I sublcass from A I override `func` and in 100% of those cases I should call `A::func();` before doing anything else? How can I prevent writing this manually. Sometimes I even forget in child class to call `A::func();` and get runtime errors, throws and so on.

Comment: Did you forget to inherit? Also, I don't think what you want is possible.

Comment: Yes Davaid, thanks. But I know that there is nothing impossible in C++ :).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about the [NVI pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern)?

```
class A
{
public:
    void func(int a)
    {
        cout << "System is initiated correctly." << a;
        do_func(a);
    }

private:
    virtual void do_func(int a) {}
};

class B : public A
{
private:
    virtual void do_func(int a) override
    {
        cout << "This particular system is initiated correctly too" << a;
    }
};
```

Comment: Damn, was going to post *exactly* that.

Comment: Of course, you need to make sure that you'll **never** need a subclass that needs not to call the base implementation.

Comment: You beat me to it. Hard.

Comment: This solves this particularly case where you are trying to "bracket" virtual override-able code (classic NVI). However this doesn't directly solve the problem of always calling subclassed virtual function much like constructors do.